# Hugo Error while rendering "page"

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I started a site using Hugo and the Minimo theme. I set the site up and it worked just fine in both my computers (one is a Windows and the other one is a Mac). However, when the other author tried to use the `render_site()` command, it throws the following error:

```
Building sites … ERROR 2018/08/11 22:49:17 Error while rendering "page" in "post\\": template: _default/single.html:1:3: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: template: partials/header.html:10:7: executing "partials/header.html" at <partial "sidebar/sid...>: error calling partial: template: partials/sidebar/sidebar.html:10:6: executing "partials/sidebar/sidebar.html" at <partial "extras/widg...>: error calling partial: template: partials/extras/widget_area.html:7:8: executing "partials/extras/widget_area.html" at <partial (print "widg...>: error calling partial: template: partials/widgets/taxonomy_cloud.html:18:5: executing "partials/widgets/taxonomy_cloud.html" at <partial "extras/taxo...>: error calling partial: template: partials/extras/taxonomy_cloud.html:32:24: executing "partials/extras/taxonomy_cloud.html" at <$Site.GetPage>: error calling GetPage: too many arguments to .Site.GetPage: [taxonomyTerm tags apresentação]. Use lookups on the form {{ .Site.GetPage "/posts/mypage-md" }}
    Building sites … ERROR 2018/08/11 22:49:18 Error while rendering "page" in "post\\": template: _default/single.html:1:3: executing "_default/single.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: template: partials/header.html:10:7: executing "partials/header.html" at <partial "sidebar/sid...>: error calling partial: template: partials/sidebar/sidebar.html:10:6: executing "partials/sidebar/sidebar.html" at <partial "extras/widg...>: error calling partial: template: partials/extras/widget_area.html:7:8: executing "partials/extras/widget_area.html" at <partial (print "widg...>: error calling partial: template: partials/widgets/taxonomy_cloud.html:18:5: executing "partials/widgets/taxonomy_cloud.html" at <partial "extras/taxo...>: error calling partial: template: partials/extras/taxonomy_cloud.html:32:24: executing "partials/extras/taxonomy_cloud.html" at <$Site.GetPage>: error calling GetPage: too many arguments to .Site.GetPage: [taxonomyTerm tags apresentação]. Use lookups on the form {{ .Site.GetPage "/posts/mypage-md" }}
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
      '"C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t minimo' execution failed with error code 1
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: running command '"C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t minimo' had status 65535 
    2: running command '"C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t minimo' had status 65535 
    3: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t minimo' had status 1
```

I've tried my best to reproduce, but to no avail. We've tried changing directories (he was using it in Google Drive, and we thought I could be the symlink issue). I don't have this problem in any of my computers.

I don't know if this is useful, but: both my computers run in portuguese and the other author uses a computer in english.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this the problem but Minimo theme requires high hugo version (can't remember exactly but needed > v0.33; v0.46 worked fine with it). Maybe check your friend's hugo version? (`blogdown::hugo_version()`)

Comment: Everything is updated, that was one of the first things we tried. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading solved the problem. There was some update in the theme that just works with the new versions, so that must take care of it.